# Reverse counter inside partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails provides a `resource_counter` inside partials.

```
= render @users
# _user.html.slim
= user_counter + 1
= user.name
```

> 1 Marvin
>   2 Starvin
>   3 Garvin

Is it possible to make the counter count in reverse?

> 3 Garvin
>   2 Starvin
>   1 Marvin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
= render @users

# _user.html.slim
= @users.count - user_counter
= user.name
```

This should reverse the displayed numbers.

---

Antek Drzewiecki commented about the difference count/size:

- `.count` might call another query to the DB
- `.size` would just calculate the size of the array

**In conclusion**, you are better to use `.size`

Comment: Watch out weather to use .count or .size. One of these will result in an additional count query on your database.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @AntekDrzewiecki I added it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe reverse the users list with:

`render @users.reverse`

Then determine the index of the user as @MrYoshiji suggested in the partial with:

`@users.size - user_counter`

Anyways just because someone downvotes my anwser, here is the proof it works.

```
a = %w(Marvin Starvin Garvin)
=> ["Marvin", "Starvin", "Garvin"]
a.reverse!
=> ["Garvin", "Starvin", "Marvin"]
user_size = a.size
=> 3
user_counter = 0
=> 0
a.each { |user| puts "#{user_size - user_counter} #{user}"; user_counter = user_counter + 1}
3 Garvin
2 Starvin
1 Marvin
```

This results correspondents with the required list he described. If you only want to reverse the counter then don't reverse the array ;)

Comment: This would return `1 Garvin
2 Starvin
3 Marvin`

Comment: Then i'd suggest what @MrYoshiji did. First reversing the array of users. Then using `@users.count - user_counter` to determine the index.

Comment: But what if he doesn't want the users to be rendered in reverse, only the counter?

Comment: Not in my ruby. ```a = %w(Marvin, Starvin, Garvin)``` would result in ```["Marvin,", "Starvin,", "Garvin"]```. Then ```a = a.reverse  (or reverse!)``` would be ```["Garvin", "Starvin,", "Marvin,"]```. Finally ```user_counter = 0; a.each { |b| puts "#{a.size - user_counter} #{b}"; user_counter = user_counter+1}``` Which is perfectly fine, the output is like he described: ```3 Garvin
2 Starvin
1 Marvin``` @GeorgeMillo.  But if you dont want the users to be rendered in reverse, just don't reverse the user array.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I misread the question, I thought he only wanted to reverse the counter.